# Differences in R2 score when using MLPRegressor alone vs. with MultiOutputRegressor in Scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am attempting to create a surrogate model for a chemical process simulation that includes flash separators and a heat exchanger (please refer to the photo). Based on my research into similar projects, I have identified the inputs and outputs as indicated in the photo. The process involves 9 chemical constituents, resulting in 12 inputs (features) and 21 outputs (targets).

I have normalized all my data, ensuring that all the values now fall within the range of 0 to 1. This normalization helps prevent any single feature from dominating the others during the modeling process.

For my initial attempt, I used the kNNregressor from scikit-learn to build the model. However, the results in terms of R2 score, MAE, and MSE were not very satisfactory. Subsequently, I tried other alternatives, namely SVR and RandomForest. For SVR, I used MultiOutputRegressor since it can only predict a single target variable. Although the R2 score remained low, I then experimented with MLPRegressor and obtained a more satisfactory R2 score. Interestingly, when I combined MultiOutputRegressor with MLPRegressor, the R2 score improved slightly (by approximately 0.05). This prompted me to explore the underlying reasons and logic behind this improvement to gain a better understanding of my model.

So why (MultiOutputRegressor with MLPRegressor) gives a higher R2 score compared to (only MLPRegressor?) Could the higher R2 score obtained with (MultiOutputRegressor with MLPRegressor) be attributed to the interdependency among my target variables?
[image]

Comment: Could you tell us more about the interdependency? Do you mean that some outputs are inputs for other outputs and they form some kind of graph? Is the graph acyclic or not? Do you care only about prediction, or is it a causal inference problem?

Comment: Regarding the interdependencies in the system, there are a few examples worth mentioning. For instance, the amount of heat released, QS102, is dependent on the molar flow rates of C5, while, on the other hand, the molar rates of C5 are determined by the molar rates of C3 minus the molar rates of C4. Technically speaking, yes, some outputs serve as inputs for other outputs due to the cyclic nature of the calculation process in this chemical simulator. My primary concern is focused on prediction performance and not a causal inference problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if i should try other machine learning models